# Helm Convert chart labels multiline string to comma-separated string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

I have labels as multiline string in `_helpers.tpl` as below. How can i convert this into comma separated list.

**_helpers.tpl**:-

```
{{- define "mongo.selectorLabels" -}}
app: {{ include "mongo.name" . }}
release: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- end }}
```

Expecting:

**teplates/yaml:-**

```
          env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: "{{- include "mongo.sidecar.pod.labels" . }}"
```

```
value: "app=mongo,release=dev"
```

Pseudo code i am trying.

**_helpers.tpl**:-

```
{{- define "mongo.sidecar.pod.labels" -}}
{{- $list := list -}}
{{- range $k, $v := ( include "mongo.selectorLabels" ) -}}
{{- $list = append $list (printf "%s=\"%s\"" $k $v) -}}
{{- end -}}
{{ join ", " $list }}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Helm `include` extension function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) *always* returns a string; so you can't use `range` to iterate over it as you've shown.  However, Helm also includes an undocumented [`fromYaml`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/engine/funcs.go#L53) extension function that can convert a YAML-format string back to object form.  So if you `include` the helper template, then invoke `fromYaml` to parse the string result, you can `range` over the result:

```
{{- range $k, $v := include "mongo.selectorLabels" . | fromYaml -}}
```

Comment: Getting ```wrong number of args for include: want 2 got 1``` error with above solution.

Comment: I missed a `.`, I'll edit it in.

Comment: Awesome, Worked like charm. Thanks a lot @David.

Answer (score 0):

I am able convert the values into `=` separated key-value pairs. How can we join these with `,` and merge as single line.

```
{{- define "mongo.sidecar.pod.labels" -}}
{{ $lines := splitList "\n" ( include "mongo.selectorLabels" .| nindent 1) -}}
{{- range $lines }}
{{- if not (. | trim | empty) -}}
{{- $kv := . | splitn ":" 2 -}}
{{ printf "%s=%s" $kv._0 ($kv._1 | trim) }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Output with the above code:-

```
         env:
            - name: MONGO_SIDECAR_POD_LABELS
              value: " app=mongo
 release=v1
"
```